# Method not found: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IEntityType Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.INavigation.get_DeclaringEntityType()

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

Microsoft Entity Framework is getting the error above on the table DocumentPropertiesOrig in SQLServer.

1. I renamed the table DocumentProperties to DocumentPropertiesOrig
   (the Orig table has constraints).
2. Then I recreated that table without the database constraints and
   named it DocumentProperties.
3. Then I could generate the user interface screen for
   DocumentProperties successfully.
4. When I tried to generate the screen on DocumentPropertiesOrig, it
   failed with the above error.

Why the constraints on the table are not allowing us to generate the user interface screen.

I get same  error even with Entity framework 6.4 and AspNetCore 3.1. , I also tried the latest version of the EF design module and still get the same error. Any help is greatly appreciated.